# Парсинг JSON последовательно

Tags: c#, json

### Здравствуйте,

Возникла такая проблема. Получаю из **1**-го запроса **2** вида ***JSON*** ответов:

```
{
  "records": {
    "Guid": "7095be52-8375-445c-922e-66d2aee17509",
    "ID": "35",
    "IDFPARTSTEP": "2",
    "IDFPARTSTEP_NAME": "IDF PART 2",
    "REQUESTOR": "dgsdg",
    "REQUESTOR_USER_ID": "ddsgsdg",
    "REQUESTOR_PHONE": "+3423",
    "REQUESTOR_BUSINESS_NAME": "sdgsdgsdgs",
    "REQUESTORDEPARTNAME": "gsdsdg",
    "INDUSTRYFOCUSGROUP": "asfasa",
    "LEGALENTITYID": "asfas",
    "REQUESTORLOCATION": "asfas",
    "MANAGER": "qfqwf"
   }
}
```

**И такой:**

```
{
  "records": {
    "Guid": "ae169d0d-5bef-4cae-aca6-0b94a9fc5d91",
    "ID": "48",
    "LICENSE_ID": "4",
    "LICENSE_ID_NAME": "qwrqwrq",
    "PAYMENT_NUM": "KZNB-666",
    "BUYER_ID": "41",
    "BUYER_ID_NAME": "fsafefa",
    "BUYER_BANK": "77",
    "BUYER_BANK_NAME": "BTA BANK CJSC",
    "BUYER_ACC": "KZ68934501",
    "SELLER_ID": "21",
    "SELLER_ID_NAME": "dqwdrqw",
    "SELLER_BANK": "41",
    "SELLER_BANK_NAME": "SIAULIU BANKAS AB",
    "SELLER_ACC": "qrdwrqwdr",
    "PAYMENT_SUM": "12000",
    "PAYMENT_CURR": "840",
    "PAYMENT_CURR_NAME": "USD",
    "PAYMENT_DATE": "05.04.2016"
  }
}
```

Задача заключается в том, чтобы спарсить в одномерный массив значения всех переменных. Например для первого массива это должно выглядеть так:

```
I1="7095be52-8375-445c-922e-66d2aee17509", I2="35", I3="2", I4="IDF PART 2" и т.д.
```

А для второго так:

```
I2="ae169d0d-5bef-4cae-aca6-0b94a9fc5d91", I2="48", I3="4", I4="qwrqwrq" и т.д.
```

Проблема заключается в том, что названия полей, которые я хочу получить разные.
Тоесть мне требуется просто последовательно записывать каждый результат. Как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: Если поля придут в другом порядке - надо записывать как пришли или как предыдущие были записаны?

Comment: Поля должны быть просто записаны как пришли.
Тоесть I5 после первого ответа должен быть "KZNB-666", а после второго "dgsdg".
До этого, чтобы распарсить ответ я использовал .[Имя поля], а тут такое не подойдет, т.к имена полей разные приходят.

Answer (score 5):

Свой json грузите в строку (`str` в примере), подключаете сборку [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
  using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

  var parsed = JToken.Parse(str);
  var array = parsed.OfType<JProperty>()
    .Select(c => c.Value.Value<string>()).ToList();
```

Всё, в `array` у нас просто линейное перечисление значений свойств.
Может и проще можно, щас на коленке просто посмотрел, как оно внутри лежит.